# How to read .rft file and use as Android Strings value

Tags: android, android-activity, rtf, android-styles

I was looking for a way to read a **.rft (or .txt)** and use the same in Android Activity text like we do from **Android strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_text">#LinkToTextFilefromResources</string>

</resources>
```

Please let me know how to do that?

If this not possible, any alternatives that works the same?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914641/import-parse-edit-and-save-rtf-documents-with-formatting-preserved-in-ipad-and & http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-documents-in-rtf-file-type

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Reader`. See the examples in the link below. Hope this helps!

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42